# How to distribute iOS application when you don't have apple developer account

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, testflight, app-distribution

How to distribute iOS application when you don't have apple developer account. Is it possible to create a public link that bunch of people can download your app using that link when you don't have apple developer account to generate any development or distribution profile?

Client just don't want this app on the AppStore so you can suggest alternative ways how to distribute app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you can't. Free accounts allow you to test on your own device locally via development certificate. You need provisioning in developer account to export `ipa` file. There are adhoc sites out there: DeployGate, AppCenter from Microsoft, etc. However, you must have `ipa` file first.